# Limit Countries that can place an order

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a site that would like to only allow the UK to buy and ship products. They would like to block all countries outside of the uk from purchasing anything from their multistore.

Comment: which shipping method you are using ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set this from system configuration.

For this from backend Go to `System` >> `Configuration` >> `General`

Here you have the `Allow Countries` dropdown. You can select allowed countries from here.

Also you can ask from your hosting provider to block website outside UK

Comment: I have spammers that our putting <option value="AU">Australia</option> for example and it'll pass that information. The above works, but I've seen it very easy to get around. Any way to stop that?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using default magento shipping methods, than go to Backend , `System > Configuration > Sales > Shipping method`  & than you can see below option.

you can change option from "`All Allowed countires`" to "`Ship to specific countires`"

than select required country that allow for shipping.

[image]

Comment: I think they are using a number of different shipping methods. I have managed to restrict it in the allow countries option under general

Comment: Glad you got solution. Than you can follow @Pankaj Pareek answer.

Comment: Sadly, the country limits in the shipping settings only works for the validation; it will still *display* the countries from the general settings (which, I think, hardly makes sense).